# Scale text to fit in a background image

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to get longer wordpress post titles to automatically scale down their size to fit into width of the backround image (which is fixed at 986px). Currently, when a title is too long, the last words will get cut off towards the end of the sentence. Please see the below site for example:
http://www.nursingassistantdegree.com/earning-a-certified-nursing-assistant-degree-can-help-break-the-single-mom-poverty-cycle/

The CSS code is below.

```
.networkNews_bg{ background:url(images/network_news_bg.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:986px; height:82px;}
.networkNews_bg h2{ font:bold 35px/82px "Myriad Pro"; color:#2a2c2e; padding:0 20px;}
```

I have seen similar topics, but none that are specifically related to auto-sizing in a CSS. How can I get the text to auto-scale down to fit within the 986px?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't autoscale text to fit within a specified width. You can rescale text using "em," "rem" or other relative text scaling unit but all of this changes the text height, not its width. Instead of scaling, how about adding an automatic ellipsis to your title?

```
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 986px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

If a title heading expands past 986px, it will show "..." This is a very simple solution.

Decreasing the font-size is also recommended if this is a common issue.

EDIT:

Here is the snapshot from FF. This is what I added. I did not change the font properties. But you can decrease it if you want. You need 3 new properties: `text-overflow, overflow, white-space`. The white-space is especially important.

Snapshot:

[image: screen shot]

Update 2:

```
networkNews_bg h2 {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        wite-space: nowrap;
        color: #2A2C2E;
        font: 35px/82px "Myriad Pro";
        padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: agreed.  Reducing the font size is probably the most effective solution without altering the design.  I don't agree with the ellipse as this is a detail page and you can't ever see the full title if that is the solution used, but changing the font size and good content management (not using super long titles) is probably the best.

Comment: Agreed. If this is a content page, then any cut out text isn't good. However, I do recommend an ellipsis IF text is to be cut out. That way the user at least knows. You can always use javascript to show the entire heading when the mouse cursor hovers over it - but this may very well be overkill.

Comment: Thank you both. I like the ellipsis idea alot. @ProfileTwist, where in my CSS file should that go? I tried putting it right under the  .networkNews_bg h2 but that did not work.

Comment: You will need to play around with the CSS a bit. I'm at work now so I do not have access to the handy FF extension, Firebug... make sure to get it! There is one piece of vital code I missed: `white-space: nowrap;` this property prevents text from wrapping and creating a new line. Be sure to add that property. You will need to change the font sizes appropriately. `font: 20px/20px;` add that property in too. See if these 2 things fixes it

Comment: When I get home later I'll throw your website into FF and help you out more if you need it.

Comment: Yes that would be great. I can't figure this out @profiletwist.  I put it in several places and it does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ProfileTwist . The only issue I am having is I do not know where to put the                    
    .ellipsis {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 986px;
      height: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }             
I have tried putting it in various areas of the CSS file but it did not work.

Comment: As the snapshot above shows, you put that code in style.css on in line 182, into the `.networkNews_bg h2 {}` code block. If after all this, you are still unable to do this, I suggest you hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up @ProfileTwist. I understand what goes on line 182, however I was referring to your original code you spoke of... the ".ellipsis" portion of the code that sets the width, height, and line-height parameters.

Comment: Do not add that code. That was a preliminary sketch. You should only add 3 new properties as per my direction in the answer. Look at the snapshot and EXACTLY copy that code. It works.

Comment: I see what happened, when I copied and pasted the code, I had not noticed that "white" was spelled "wite" in your code.  Once I changed the spelling error it worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for your help @ProfileTwist

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your css for the background to be

```
background: url(images/network_news_bg.png) bottom no-repeat;
```

and then edit your image to be much taller.  repeating the top upward if that makes sense.  Then remove the height restriction and style accordingly with line height.

Comment: So to clarify @JosephMarikle, you are suggesting to not mess with the text, but to make the background image expand vertically down the page to accomodate the text?

Comment: @user2441792 Yes.  Sorry I didn't clarify that.  Changing the text's horizontal width dynamically is just asking for it to break on a the various different browsers.  Font's are not rendered the same on all browsers and this makes font scaling difficult.  The most common approach is to just allow the content to expand it's container making it dynamic and adaptable to its environment.

Comment: ok that makes a lot of sense @JosephMarikle. Thank you for the tip. How would I write the CSS to repeat top upward?   Also, it would automatically know to repeat this if the text is too large to be on one line?

Comment: You can't really do that with CSS alone.  You would need to replace the image.  Something like this: http://i2.minus.com/iSL61RxoJYKPW.png